# Can format like "May 17, 2017", "17/5/2017" or "17-5-17 05:24:39" be used in as.POSIXlt?

Tags: r, posix, transformation, posixlt

I've just read about the difference between `POSIXlt` and `POSIXct` and it is said that POSIXlt is a mixed text and character format like "May, 6 1985", "1990-9-1" or "1/20/2012". When I try such kind of things I get an error

```
as.POSIXlt("May, 6 1985")
# character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

(How) can we dates with format as quoted above put forward to `POSIXlt`? Here are sources saying that such format works (if I get them right): [1](http://ianmadd.github.io/pages/POSIXct_and_POSIXlt.html), [2](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2012/11/whats-the-difference-between-posixct-and-posixlt/).

Comment: You can read about `?strptime` or take a look at the `anytime` package: http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/anytime.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read `?strptime` for all the details of specifying a time format. In this case you want `%b` (for month name), `%d` (day of month), `%Y` (4-digit year). (This will only work with an English locale setting as the month names are locale-specific.)

```r
as.POSIXlt("May, 6 1985", format = "%b, %d %Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have mixed input of formates you can use `parse_date_time` from the `lubridate` package.

```
x <- c("May, 6 1985", "1990-9-1", "1/20/2012")

y <- lubridate::parse_date_time(x, c("ymd", "mdy", "dmy"))

str(y)
# POSIXct[1:3], format: "1985-05-06" "1990-09-01" "2012-01-20"
```

**note** on `c("ymd", "mdy", "dmy")` as this determines the order on first found first converted. Consider `6-1-2000` will encounter `mdy` as valid before `dmy` so this means it will be first of June and not sixth of January.